# Dialer only displays certain contacts even when all accounts selected

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-4, exchange, phone-app

I am using a Samsung Galaxy S4 with Lollipop 5.0.1. It seems that only gmail contacts will display while searching via Dialer. If it is linked or solely on my Microsoft Exchange account they do not show up. They are in my contacts tab. Any thoughts?